# How to handle a list of dynamic webelements on mobile app automation (SeeTest/JavaScript/BDD)

Tags: javascript, bdd, mobile-application, webdriver-io, seetest

First time here.

I have automated a dynamic page with a list of questions that change each time you land on that page. Sometimes it might be a checkbox and sometimes a date field or a radio button. For desktop, I am handling it by getting the objectlist and answering each question based on whether it a radio button, checkbox, date field.

My issue is that sometimes the question has a subquestion. My desktop code is fine. But on the mobile app, we have to swipe to each question one by one.

In my desktop code, the first loop, the first question gets answered. In the second iteration, the subquestions will get answered.

This takes too long for mobile app.

Is there a better of handling this on the app?  I am using SeeTest, JavaScript, BDD, Cucumber/Gherkin.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you show an example of the app code and the test?